# bind_param() dinâmico

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class BindParam{
    private $values = array(), $types = '';

    public function add( $type, &$value ){
        $this->values[] = $value;
        $this->types .= $type;
    }

    public function get(){
        return array_merge(array($this->types), $this->values);
    }
}
```

e este é meu código para gerar o sql:

```
if(!empty($dataIni)){
    $qArray[] = "BETWEEN V.DATA_EMISSAO ?";
    $bindParam->add('s', $dataIni);
}
if(!empty($dataFim)){
    $qArray[] = "?";
    $bindParam->add('s', $dataFim);
}
$queryNFe .= implode(' AND ', $qArray);
$param = $bindParam->get();
$sqlNFe = $mysqli->prepare($queryNFe);
call_user_func_array(array($sqlNFe, 'bind_param'), $param);
$sqlNFe->execute();
```

A clausula da consulta esta montando certo, o erro esta na call_user_func_array()

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in

Sei que é no primeiro parametro mas não estou conseguindo ver o que esta errado

Mudei o código:

```
if(!empty($dataIni)){
    $qArray[] = "V.DATA_EMISSAO BETWEEN ?";
    $bindParam->add('s', $dataIni);
}
if(!empty($dataFim)){
    $qArray[] = "?";
    $bindParam->add('s', $dataFim);
}
$queryNFe .= implode(' AND ', $qArray);
$param = $bindParam->get();
$sqlNFe = $mysqli->prepare($queryNFe) or die($mysqli->error);
call_user_func_array(array($sqlNFe, 'bind_param'), $bindParam->get());
//$sqlNFe->bind_param('ss', $dataIni, $dataFim); 
$sqlNFe->execute();
```

Mas agora o erro é este:

> Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in

Comment: QUando vc passa, manualmente os valores para `bind_param` da certo ou aparece algum erro?

Comment: se passar assim: $sqlNfe->bind_param('ss', $dataInicio, $dataFim) funciona sem problema

Comment: Veja se isso retorna outro erro, `$mysqli->prepare($queryNFe) or die($mysqli->error);`

Comment: sem erro @rray.

Comment: Agora o erro é mais simples, vc precisa passar o array por refêrencia e não como retorno de método ... uma vez resolvi assim `foreach($values as $valores){ $ref[] = &$valores;}` ... talvez exista algo melhor.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, já coloquei a solução usando um foreach() @rray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi aqui com essa função:

```
function refValues($arr){
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
    {
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        return $refs;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

dai foi só alterar:

```
call_user_func_array(array($sqlNFe, 'bind_param'), refValues($param));
```

Obrigado